# viewing printf after pipe (or subshell?)

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe, debugging, subshell

Ok, this is hard to distill to a single question because it really depends on how I'm going to troubleshoot it.

The following script is meant to pipe mount.cifs commands to a while loop that enters password for three password prompts.  The commented out blocks are attempts to debug the fact that it isn't responding to the prompt.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "How many atoms are there in the universe?\nAnswer:"
read -s $pwd
echo -e "\nThanks.\n"
while read prompt ; do
#     printf "prompt = $prompt" > /dev/stdout
#     ${prompt//"\n"/"\\n"}
#     printf "prompt is" >foo
    if [ "$prompt" = "Password: " ]; then
    echo -e "$pwd\r\n" > /dev/stdin
    fi
done < <(
    sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.2/My Music" /home/pi/Desktop/Music -o     user=Rob_
    sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.2/My Videos" /home/pi/Desktop/Videos -o     user=Rob_
    sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.2/My Pictures" /home/pi/Desktop    /Pictures -o user=Rob_
)
```

The 'prompt' variable does not seem to meet the condition, but the debug printouts are being swallowed up even after manually redirecting to /dev/stdout?

If someone could at the very least tell me how I can print debug info in this scenario I would be grateful, and if they want to tell me how to solve this problem outright (preferably by the method I was shooting for, but if you have a more elegant one I'd be interested to see it) then I'd appreciate that, too.

EDIT: For the record I'm aware that you can supply the password directly to the command, I'm just doing this as a test for myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've since tried tackling the problem from a different angle, using the 'expect ' command.  However the following fails to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo mount.cifs "//192.168.1.2/My Pictures" /home/pi/Desktop/Pictures -o user=Rob_
expect "Password: " {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    send -s "a_password"
}
```

It responds to the password prompt by typing it in, but fails to mount the drive, so I'm not sure where the input is going to.  I can supply any old garbage with 'send' and it happily closes without an error message, whereas if I enter the command from the shell it either protests that the password is wrong or mounts successfully.

I'll upload this as a separate question if noone answers here.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple reasons:

- Your debug printf didn't work, because mount prints its prompt to the terminal, not stdout. `read prompt` failed and the loop was never entered.
- You are trying to echo the password to `/dev/stdin`. This will not work, you can only read from it.
- the `mount`'s stdin is still connected to the terminal. There is no way to emulate user typing in terminal
- Even if you make `mount`'s stdin be a pipe, for security reasons mount will still detect the terminal and read from it, not pipe

What you actually need is a password file. Read `man mount.cifs`:

> credentials=filename

You can try to supply a fake password file using bash command substitutuon:

```
credentials=<( echo "password=$pwd" )
```

Comment: As far as I can see a password file is itself a security liability.  I want it so that an actual human has to type in the password (and only once, despite there being three prompts)

Comment: @RobF `You can try to supply a fake password file`

Comment: The original question was mainly about why the debug printf's that were commented out weren't showing in the console.  As to the password file; it seems a password supplied through PASSWD_FILE (with the proper formatting, I didn't make that mistake), PASSWD, the password= parameter in the options; all get ignored and I get prompted for the password anyway!?  I can also enter any garbage as the credentials file and it won't show an error.I might want to look into this as a separate problem if you don't know the answer...

Comment: @RobF Your debug printf didn't work, because `mount prints its prompt to the terminal, not stdout`

Comment: `read prompt` failed and the loop was never entered